# Concatenate records from same column?

Tags: postgresql

I have written a query with the following purpose: there are four visits (visname) in my "DAT_PAGS" dataset:
Pre-procedure,
Procedure,
Post-Procedure,
End of Study

If for any of these visits in the table, there are both records with statusid ='0' and statusid = '5' (i.e. entered or no data), I want the page names (pagename) to appear in my output (see below).

My question is twofold:
-Is there a way to concatenate all the pagenames per visit in my output? So that I have only one row per subnum?

-Is there a better way to do this? I am still getting the hang of SQL, so if this is a ridiculous approach, feedback is much appreciated!

My query:

```
SELECT

DISTINCT "DAT_SUB".SUBNUM as "Subject ID",

nodatapreproc.pagename as "Pre-Procedure",

nodataproc.pagename as "Procedure",

nodatapostproc.pagename as "Post-Procedure",

nodataEOS as "End Of Study"

FROM 

"Disco_Radial"."DAT_SUB"
LEFT JOIN (SELECT subnum, visname, pagename, statusid FROM "Disco_Radial"."DAT_PAGS" where 
("Disco_Radial"."DAT_PAGS".statusid = '5' AND "DAT_PAGS".visname = 'Post-Procedure')) postprocentered 
on "DAT_SUB".subnum = postprocentered.subnum
LEFT JOIN (SELECT subnum, visname, pagename, statusid FROM "Disco_Radial"."DAT_PAGS" where 
("Disco_Radial"."DAT_PAGS".statusid = '0' AND "DAT_PAGS".visname = 'Post-Procedure')) nodatapostproc 
ON nodatapostproc.subnum = postprocentered.subnum
LEFT JOIN (SELECT subnum, visname, pagename, statusid FROM "Disco_Radial"."DAT_PAGS" where 
("Disco_Radial"."DAT_PAGS".statusid = '5' AND "DAT_PAGS".visname = 'Pre-Procedure')) preprocentered 
on "DAT_SUB".subnum = preprocentered.subnum
LEFT JOIN (SELECT subnum, visname, pagename, statusid FROM "Disco_Radial"."DAT_PAGS" where 
("Disco_Radial"."DAT_PAGS".statusid = '0' AND "DAT_PAGS".visname = 'Pre-Procedure')) nodatapreproc ON 
nodatapreproc.subnum = preprocentered.subnum
LEFT JOIN (SELECT subnum, visname, pagename, statusid FROM "Disco_Radial"."DAT_PAGS" where 
("Disco_Radial"."DAT_PAGS".statusid = '5' AND "DAT_PAGS".visname = 'Procedure')) procentered on 
"DAT_SUB".subnum = procentered.subnum
LEFT JOIN (SELECT subnum, visname, pagename, statusid FROM "Disco_Radial"."DAT_PAGS" where 
("Disco_Radial"."DAT_PAGS".statusid = '0' AND "DAT_PAGS".visname = 'Procedure')) nodataproc ON 
nodataproc.subnum = procentered.subnum
LEFT JOIN (SELECT subnum, visname, pagename, statusid FROM "Disco_Radial"."DAT_PAGS" where 
("Disco_Radial"."DAT_PAGS".statusid = '5' AND "DAT_PAGS".visname = 'End Of Study')) EOSentered on 
"DAT_SUB".subnum = EOSentered.subnum
LEFT JOIN (SELECT subnum, visname, pagename, statusid FROM "Disco_Radial"."DAT_PAGS" where 
("Disco_Radial"."DAT_PAGS".statusid = '0' AND "DAT_PAGS".visname = 'End Of Study')) nodataEOS ON 
nodataEOS.subnum = EOSentered.subnum

ORDER BY "DAT_SUB".subnum;
```

Part of my output:

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that with conditional aggregation

```
SELECT ds.subnum as "Subject ID",
       string_agg(pagename, ',') filter (where dp.statusid = '0' AND dp.visname = and 'Pre-Procedure') as "Pre-Procedure",
       string_agg(pagename, ',') filter (where dp.statusid = '5' AND dp.visname = and 'Pre-Procedure') as "???",
       string_agg(pagename, ',') filter (where dp.statusid = '0' AND dp.visname = and 'Procedure') as "Procedure",
       string_agg(pagename, ',') filter (where dp.statusid = '0' AND dp.visname = and 'Post-Procedure') as "Post-Procedure",
       string_agg(pagename, ',') filter (where dp.statusid = '5' AND dp.visname = and 'Post-Procedure') as "?????",
       string_agg(pagename, ',') filter (where dp.statusid = '0' AND dp.visname = and 'End Of Study') as "End Of Study"
FROM "Disco_Radial"."DAT_SUB" ds
  LEFT JOIN "Disco_Radial"."DAT_PAGS" dp ON ds.subnum = dp.subnum
GROUP BY ds.subnum;
```

Comment: Thank you, this does indeed work! Any idea how I would incorporate the condition that for this subject ID there should also be at least one record where statusid = '5'?

Comment: Update: I tried this by adding '(SELECT 1  WHERE "DAT_PAGS".statusid = '5' and "DAT_PAGS".visname = 'Pre-Procedure')' to the filter. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ZegherV: there is no need to use a `SELECT` inside the `filter()` clause - but the `and` was indeed missing